# MySQL slow importing on hyper-v virtual server compared to host

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-8.0

**Database dump file:**

- 6 MB size
- 14k rows
- 10 tables

**Server specs (Ubuntu 20.04, virtual (hyper-v)):**

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- MySQL version: Ver 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 for Linux on x86_64
  ((Ubuntu))
- 4 core, 2 GB RAM
- 100 GB storage

**Host MySQL**

- Windows server
- MySQL version: 8.0.17 - MySQL Community Server - GPL
- HDD Storage
- 8 GB RAM

Importing dump to the database on the host machine took 1-3 seconds, importing on the guest server 5-6 minutes.

iotop reports maximum write speed 5 MB/s while importing.

Refreshing database on phpmyadmin, i can see all row is imported after 1 minutes, the rest of the time is just altering table:

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
   MODIFY `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;
```

**Import command:**

```
mysql -u user -p db < /home/user/dump.sql
```

tried:

- mysql-server reinstall on guest machine
- disable unique checks with UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
- disable foreign key checks with FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

Comment: check the mysql error log of your new server,  see if there are problems. Did you chekcn the my.cnf file if the caches tmp file and so on are similiar

Comment: Got the exact same problem, mysql import very slow on my dev machine after upgrade to 20.04. Some servers are fine after upgrade, and I compared versions & configs: they are EXACTLY the same!?

Also, no errors in syslog or mysql log.

Comment: @SimonEpskamp Your server is dedicated or virtual?

Comment: @X11 my servers are dedicated (where it works fine), and my dev machine dedicted as well of course.

Comment: Did you check to see if any indexes or histograms made it onto the new server?

Comment: From your Hyper V server, Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
\F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
From your Ubuntu Command Prompt, 
htop or top - ulimit -a   for list of limits - 
iostat -xm 5 3 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning on: "Turn off Windows write-cache buffer" solved the issue for me.
(no restart required for me)

[image: Turn off Windows write-cache buffer]

Benchmark write speed, before and after the setting.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test2.img bs=512 count=1000 oflag=dsync
```

[image: Benchmark write speed, before and after the setting.]

Comment: Thanks so much, your answer pointed me in the right direction. I'm posting a full answer below.

Comment: This is not solving the problem - it is hiding the problem behind another one. Did you bother READING the warning? You basically invite data corruption if power EVER fails.

Answer (score 0):

**Test SSD speed to see if that's the problem**

Follow this [guide](https://medium.com/@kenichishibata/test-i-o-performance-of-linux-using-dd-a5074f1de9ce):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test2.img bs=512 count=1000 oflag=dsync
```

For me (Samsung evo 860 SSD) the results before the fix were around **80 kB/s**.

**Fix SSD speed if it's slow**

Follow this [guide](https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/ssd.html). One of the fixes suggested is to `trim` all SSDs:

```
sudo fstrim -av
```

You will it trim the amount equal to the free space on your disk. **Follow up by rebooting the system**

After reboot, my writespeeds were up to **280 kB/s**, and mysql import was at a normal speed again.

Comment: 280 kB/s is too slow i think, the benchmark gives me 1.1 MB/s tested on 970 evo plus.

Comment: It's a VM under windows.

Comment: I think you're right, now my performance has dropped again. I'll have to investigate further, perhaps upgrade my ssd firmware.

Comment: @X11 after looking at some other results online, I think the perf is quite normal. The difference with you may be due to the VM / the windows settings you made. See: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bs%3D512+count%3D1000+oflag%3Ddsync%22

Comment: YOu should not, never ever, use an EVO ssd in virtualization - they are VERY read oriented with a VERY pathetic endurance for writes. Which means you burn it out basically by patching VM's alone. They are meant for "very read centric" things - like the boot system of ONE OS and then storing games or other large files. This may be totally alone part of the problem.

Comment: @TomTom such hyperbole is not needed. X11 already solved his problem.

Comment: It is not hyperbole - I had the happy scenario to have a server with EVO ssd and we burned them out in 6 months with basically a small database.

Comment: @TomTom I just using it for testing on my PC, on the server i use HDD-s for storage.